# ng-repeat does not render array items from Jsonp Server

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

So here I go with my first question. 
I am trying to use ng-repeat to render data from the server, but it's not displaying anything. 
this is the code for my controller

```
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $http) {   
var url = "https://lari.jumpstart.ge/en/api/v1/commercial_banks?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

       $http.jsonp(url)
            .success(function(data) {

                $scope.results =   data.results;
          })
            .error(function(data) {
              alert("ERROR");
            });


});
```

this is the ng-repeat in my view

```
<ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content >
          <ion-item ng-controller='ExampleController' ng-repeat='x in results'> 


         {{x.code}} 


</ion-item>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is the array on the server

```
{  
   "valid":true,
   "results":[  
      {  
         "code":"BAGA",
         "name":"Bank Of Georgia",
         "currencies":[  
            "AED",
            "AMD",
            "AUD",
         ]
      },
      {  
         "code":"TBCB",
         "name":"TBC Bank",
         "currencies":[  
            "AED",
            "AUD",
            "AZN", 
         ]
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The erroneous code has the `ng-controller` directive on the same node as the `ng-repeat` directive.

```
<!-- Replace THIS
<ion-content >
     <ion-item ng-controller='ExampleController' ng-repeat='x in results'> 
         {{x.code}} 
     </ion-item>
</ion-content>
-->

<!-- With THIS -->
<ion-content ng-controller='ExampleController' >
     <ion-item ng-repeat='x in results'> 
         {{x.code}} 
     </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

The `ng-repeat` directive needs to be on a child node from the `ng-controller`.

Answer (score 0):

$http returns a promise though. check the error in the console and see what it says. Look into moving the code in the controller into a factory/service and then assign, whatever value this controller or service returns, to the $scope

Answer (score 0):

If the example you give of the array on your server is correct, then all you need to do is change `$scope.results = data.results;` to `$scope.results = data.results.results;`, because otherwise it will not be able to iterate over the array of your response data. On the other hand, if that doesn't work, try changing `{{x.code}}` to `{{x}}` to see what the output is.